# Find angle between two points in Flash/Box2D

Tags: flash, box2d

I wrote this function to find the angle between two points:

```
protected function angleCalc (x1:Number, y1:Number, x2:Number, y2:Number):Number
{
    var dx:Number = x2 - x1;
    var dy:Number = y2 - y1;
    var j:Number = Math.atan2(dy,dx) * Constants.RADIANS_TO_DEGREES;
    return j;
}
```

However, the results don't match what I'm looking for.
How can I calculate the angle between two points?

Comment: This looks good if your RADIANS_TO_DEGREES equals 180 / Math.PI . Are you sure that you are passing x and y coordinates in the correct order to your function ? :)

Comment: There's nothing wrong with this code at all so long as RADIANS_TO_DEGREES is 180/pi, as @Philarmon said.  Could you post some examples of points you're passing in and the results you're expecting?